# CKFinder 3.x ASP.net Physical Path

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder

Hello Every one i have a problem here with CKFinder 3.x ASP.NET. So i downloaded a Zip File and ran it through IIS and Ran some samples so it worked. Then i have my Website i want to implement the same idea in there. So i went deleted the sample test CKFinder 3.x ASP.net that was running under IIS. Then i Reinstalled the CKFinder and Unpacked it in my website where i want it to be working in. Then i ran the sample pages such as /Ckfinder/ckfinder.html. It says 
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.
{Requested URL--  http://localhost:80/ckfinder/connector?command=Init&lang=en}
{Physical Path--C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ckfinder\connector}
But i was running it through my web site it was suppose to go through  {C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My-Web-site\ckfinder\connector}
But instead its looking for CkFinder straight in my wwwroot folder some how i dont know where to change it so it goes through my website where the folder CkFinder exists.
Where do i change the default Path. in web.config or which file?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [quick start guide](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html) and especially this [part](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html).

- First of all, your CKFinder zip package needs to be converted to application.
- Second you need to set [connectorPath](https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-connectorPath) in config.js. If you have converted CKFinder folder into application then `connectoPath` should look like so: `config.connectoPath = My-Web-site\ckfinder\connector;`.

  - Finally, you should also set correct path to [userfiles folder](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends_local). If it is used in default location then path should look more or less like in the snippet below.

Sample Backend configuration:

```
<backend name="myBackend" adapter="local">
  <option name="root" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My-Web-site\ckfinder\userfiles" />
  <option name="baseUrl" value=" http://localhost:80/My-Web-site/ckfinder/userfiles" />
</backend>
```

Comment: That didnt change it. It only changed the path for the Connector and it shows a black screen i did exactly as you said in config.js after or even before i tried both `CKFinder.define(config)` i set the `config.connectoPath = we-site/ ckfinder / connector` So it ddint work blank screen  and then when i call the CKfinder.start i said ` CKFinder.basePath = config.connectoPath` still blank screen now

Comment: You have installed CKFinder from zip folder. Have you converted CKFinder to application? I'm sorry but I haven't written anything about basePath and haven’t heard that it has to be set as well.
Please check browser dev-tools if you are getting any JavaScript errors or HTTP errors like 404.
Please also enable CKFinder logging and check CKFinder logs - http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/debugging.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Solved as stated in the documentation here :
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_configuration_authentication

Adding this appconfig section to the `ckfinder` subfolder web.config file :

```
<add key="ckfinderAllowedRole" value="*" />
```